# Dafny multisets

Tags: theorem-proving, dafny, multiset

In a reference manual ([http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~se2011/DafnyDocumentation/Dafny%20-%20ValueTypes.pdf](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Ese2011/DafnyDocumentation/Dafny%20-%20ValueTypes.pdf)), we can find: *two multisets are equal if they have exactly the same count of each element*. However, there is no violation if I assert:

```
   assert multiset({1,1}) == multiset{1};
```

So I am understanding something wrong.

Then, for instance, to prove this:

```
lemma seqSplit(s:seq<int>, c:int, p:int, f:int)
       requires 0<=c<=p<=f+1<=|s|
       ensures multiset(s[c..f+1]) == multiset(s[c..p])+multiset(s[p..f+1])
```

What is is necessary? I started with:

```
       assert forall i :: c<=i<=f ==> 
              (s[i] in multiset(s[c..f+1]) <==> (s[i] in multiset(s[c..p]) || s[i] in multiset(s[p..f+1])));
```

It verifies, and I would say it is the same as in the ensures, but seems not. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiset({1,1})` means "construct the *set* `{1,1}`, and then convert it to a multiset". Since the set `{1,1}` and the set `{1}` are the same, your assertion passes.

I think you want `multiset{1,1}`.

Comment: Does "construct the set {1,1}, and then convert it to a multiset" more or less mean "construct a set from {1,1}, and then convert it to a multiset"?

Comment: right. the key is that `multiset{...}` is its own syntactic construct which is completely separate from `{...}` for sets.